# FragmentPagerAdapter class is deprecated. How to solve FragmentPagerAdapter issue

Tags: java, android-studio, android-layout, android-viewpager2, fragmentpageradapter

**FragmentPagerAdapter class is deprecated**

*Since API 27 FragmentPagerAdapter is deprecated. What's the best alternative to use for this?*

> [How to solve FragmentPagerAdapter issue.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71185247/fragmentpageradapter-class-is-deprecated-how-to-solve-fragmentpageradapter-issu)

- Follow my code you easily solve this problem.

**imports :**

```
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentPagerAdapter
```

**My Old Code :**

```
public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    
  public PagerAdapter(@NonNull FragmentActivity fragmentActivity) {
        super(fragmentActivity);

    }
int tab_count;
public PagerAdapter(@NonNull FragmentManager fm, int behavior) {
    super(fm, behavior);
    tab_count=behavior;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    switch (position)
    {
        case 0 : return new Ftab1();
        case 1 : return new ftab2();
        case 2 : return new Ftab3();
        default: return null;
    }
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return tab_count;
}
```

**My New Code :**

- Follow my code you easily solve this problem.
  Note:
- Replace FragmentPagerAdapter with FragmentStateAdapter
- Create string of your fragment name
- In XML & JAVA File,Replace ViewPager with [**ViewPager2**](https://developer.android.com/training/animation/vp2-migration).
- Done

  ```
   public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentStateAdapter {

   String[] fragment_names = new String[]{"chat","status","call"};
   public PagerAdapter(@NonNull FragmentActivity fragmentActivity) {
       super(fragmentActivity);

   }

   @NonNull
   @Override
   public Fragment createFragment(int position) {
       switch (position)
       {
           case 0 : return new Ftab1();
           case 1 : return new ftab2();
           case 2 : return new Ftab3();
           default: return null;
       }

   }

   @Override
   public int getItemCount() {
       return fragment_names.length;
   }
  ```

  }

Comment: Switch to ViewPager2

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this seems to be a combined question/answer, but should be split into a question and separate answer.